# MagicSuggest fail with php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hi i'm using Magicsuggest library Here's [a link](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html). So i encounter with this errors when i try to connect to mysql

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

The tag table contain two column the id and name of the tag. So how can i fix this error. Thanks for help. Here it's my php file

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",'root', '','freelancer');

$query = "SELECT * FROM tag";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
        placeholder: 'Các kỹ năng yêu cầu',
        allowDuplicates: false,
        maxSelection: 2,
        data: '/valid/tags.php'
    });
});
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the query actually succeeded and returned something?

Comment: MagicSuggest is a JavaScript library, so can you show us your client side code? Plus, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` is a JavaScript error you would see in the browser console.

Comment: @DaveChen here it's my client code

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
        placeholder: 'Các kỹ năng yêu cầu',
        allowDuplicates :false,
        maxSelection :2,
        data:'/valid/tags.php'
    });
});

Comment: @MarcB i try to var_dump and i see the result

Comment: Is that all? Where do you call `var_dump`?

Comment: @DaveChen in the tags.php file everything is ok,I think there is problem with the js file

Comment: Yep there's something wrong on the client side, can you post your entire JavaScript?

Comment: here it's 
http://codepaste.net/daaoiu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102053/discussion-between-hoang-phuc-v-and-dave-chen).